# Setting up IPv6 on a router behind another router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

I have a [TP-Link Archer C2 AC750 (V1)](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/cat-5506_Archer-C2.html) router. It works well for IPv4 but I am not able to setup IPv6.

### Network topology

The discussed router shares internet connection to devices in my flat (Macs and iPhones of various age). The WAN port of the router is connected to the house router which shares a common DSL connection (the ISP is [O2 Czech Republic](https://www.o2.cz/osobni/en)) across the building using Ethernet.

### Direct connection

I can connect one of my Macs directly to the wired house network. It gets all needed information for both IPv4 and IPv6 connection. The webpage http://whatismyipaddress.com opened in Safari shows my public IPv6 address (beginning with `2a00:`, so no [6to4 tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4)).

Full listing follows. I am hiding my MAC and IPv6 addresses for privacy reason.

```
$ ifconfig en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.0.0.63 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 2a00:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx prefixlen 64 autoconf 
    inet6 2a00:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <half-duplex>)
    status: active

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep -v '^#'
domain .
nameserver 10.0.0.138
nameserver fe80::1
```

### Current router settings

The IPv6 configuration of my router follows. I am hiding the IP address for privacy reason. The first half of the address (64-bit prefix) is still the same.

**IPv6 Status**

```
- WAN
Connection Type: Dynamic IPv6
Connection Status: Connected
IPv6 Address: 2a00:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx /64
IPv6 Default Gateway: fe80::0000:0000:0000:0001
Primary IPv6 DNS: ::
Secondary IPv6 DNS: ::
- IPv6 LAN
IPv6 Address Type: RADVD
Prefix Length: 64
IPv6 Address: N/A
```

**IPv6 WAN**

[image: IPv6 WAN settings]

When I change the *Addressing Type* to the only other option, `DHCPv6`, the router never gets an IPv6 address.

**IPv6 LAN**

[image: IPv6 LAN settings (RADVD)]

or

[image: IPv6 LAN settings (DHCPv6)]

Regardless of whether I choose `RADVD` or `DHCPv6` with Delegated prefix, my computer never gets an IPv6 address. My computer gets *some* IPv6 address with `DHCPv6` and Static prefix but it still cannot connect the IPv6 internet. It cannot even ping either router.

Can anyone help me with this settings? Or, since some people report that the IPv6 support of TP-Link routers is incomplete (e.g. https://lkhill.com/its-2015-supports-ipv6-should-mean-full-support/), should I rather switch to [OpenWrt](https://wiki.openwrt.org/start)?

---

### EDIT

Unfortunately, later I realized that OpenWrt is not yet ready for my router, see [OpenWrt Wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/ac750) and [OpenWrt Discussion](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=52625&p=4) for details.

Since [@Michael Hampton](https://superuser.com/users/144961/michael-hampton) suspected the upstream (house) router to be misbehaving, I am showing its current *IPv6 LAN Auto Configuration* settings.

[image: IPv6 LAN Auto Configuration of the house router]

I tried to disable *M-bit custom mode* but no change…

### EDIT 2

The *IPv6 information* in the house router is following. Again, the IP address is hidden for privacy reason.

```
IPv6 enable/disabled:   Enabled
IPv6 Primary DNS Server:    2a00:1028:1:910::1
IPv6 Secondary DNS Server:  2a00:1028:1:911::1
Active IPv6 Prefix:  
Active IPv6 Prefix Length:   
LAN interface Link-Local address:   fe80::0:0:0:1
Manual configured prefix:    
WAN interface Link-Local address:   fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
WAN interface User Setting Global address:  2A00:1028:xxxx:xxxx:0:0:0:1/64
IPv6 DefaultGateway:    fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
LAN IPv6 Address:    
Default IPv6 interface Gateway:
```

Comment: Does the upstream router support Prefix Delegation? Because if it doesn’t, this never going to work.

Comment: @DanielB I am not sure but the IPv6 connectivity worked with the router of my former flatmate (on the place of my current TP-Link router).

Comment: Hm. Are you sure the previous router was actually a router and not, say, a switch? Perhaps you need to explicitly allow PD for specific devices in the upstream router. What make and model is the upstream router?

Comment: @DanielB Well, it turns out that it was probably configured as a switch. I have just found my end devices in the list of DHCP leases of the upstream router (as expired). The upstream router seems to be Comtrend VR-3026e (I do not have physical access to it at the moment).

Comment: I'll always go with putting OpenWrt on a home router, but in this case, your immediate problem is that the upstream Comtrend whatever router is misbehaving. That's what you need to look at.

Comment: The IP address is hidden for privacy reasons?  fe80: doesn't look hidden.  I guess you mean 2a00:1028: is meant to represent another address.  2001:db8: is officially reserved for documentation so would have been a more proper choice.

Comment: @TOOGAM You mean `fe80::0:0:0:1`? It’s the [link-local](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Local_addresses) LAN address of the router, something like `192.168.1.1` in IPv4. So I find unnecessary to hide this.

Comment: @Melebius : "unnecessary to hide this"?  I know.  That's why I said that information "doesn't look hidden".  I'm assuming that's not what it was meant to hide.  By the way, the equivalent of FE80: is not "192.168." but rather "169.254." (both of those are "link-local", with the key difference being that "FE80:" is expected to work, whereas "169.254" is typically a sentence for failure since IPv4 devices often don't use multiple IP addresses on one interface, and might not support multiple IPv4 addresses as well).  The IPv6 equivalent of "192.168." is anything starting with "FE" (FE00::-FEFF:)

Comment: @TOOGAM You are right that 169.254.x.x is a better matching equivalent. However, I’m still not getting the point. `2001:1028::` contains the actual range of IP addresses given by my ISP. However, I am hiding actual public IPv6 addresses (except for ISP’s DNS servers) and those containing MAC addresses.

Comment: The point is: Why not also hide the ISP's address range? I mean, if you're going to be hiding addresses, why not do it all the way? (And, by doing so, also provide the ISP anonymity by making that part of the address ambiguous as well?)  I've seen plenty of people refer to something like ###.###.###.xxx without realizing that publishing the "###.###.###." significantly narrows things down, for potential attackers.  If you disagree, that's fine. As long as you understand that starting addresses with 2001:db8: is a good way to actually anonymize (if you want to), I reached my instructional goal.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the house router gets the range of IP addresses with the prefix `/64` which seems to be not divisible into multiple subnets.

> An IPv6 address is eight groupings of numbers:
>
> - Network address - the first three groupings of numbers (first 48 bits) in the subnet mask
> - Subnet address - the fourth grouping of numbers (the 49th through 64th bits) in the subnet mask
> - Device address - the last four groupings of numbers (the last 64 bits) in the subnet mask

> Source: [IBM Knowledge Center – Subnet masks (IPv4) and prefixes (IPv6)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STCMML8/com.ibm.storage.ts3500.doc/opg_3584_IPv4_IPv6_prefix_subnet_mask.html)

The ISP seems to be not following the [Recommendations on IPv6 Address Allocations to Sites](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3177).

> In particular, it recommends the assignment of
> /48 in the general case, /64 when it is known that one and only one
> subnet is needed and /128 when it is absolutely known that one and
> only one device is connecting.

### Further reading

- [IPv6 addresses to be allocated as /56 slices. Or will they?](https://rednectar.net/2011/10/20/ipv6-addresses-to-be-allocated-as-56-slices-or-will-they/)

## Alternative

I got IPv6 working by setting up the router as a switch. However, this means that all the devices and traffic on the subordinate (flat) network are exposed to the upstream (house) network.

### Instructions

1. Manually set the LAN IPv4 address of the subordinate router. You will need it to access the configuration of that router, at least the parts that will be applicable after the transition, for example Wi-fi.

- If you can influence the upstream router configuration, reserve a static IPv4 address in the configuration of the upstream router.
- Otherwise set an address from a different range, for example if the upstream router supplies 10.0.x.x addresses, use 192.168.x.x. You’ll have to configure your computer to use the same range whenever you need to access the router configuration.

2. Turn off the DHCP server (both IPv4 and IPv6) of the subordinate router.
3. Disconnect the upstream cable from the WAN port and connect it to a LAN port.

Based on: http://it.cestuji.info/modem-jako-switch.php (in Czech)

Comment: Well I wouldn’t really call that a solution. I’d rather forgo IPv6 than expose my internal network to others.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, this is _kind of_ a way, not the preferred one. I am still asking for a better solution.

Comment: @DanielB: How exactly do you want to avoid "exposing your internal network to others" in IPv6? Global IPv6 addresses are reachable from everywhere, and IPv6 NAT is icky. Ok, you can stop link-local broadcasts etc. by not briding, but that's about all you can do, I think.

Comment: @dirkt How to it? Well by using a firewall of course. You can use connection tracking even without NAT. Unrelated traffic is simply dropped.

Comment: @DanielB: If you want a firewall, then add a firewall. That's unrelated to the question of "routing or bridging".

Comment: @dirkt Well you could certainly use `ebtables` or whatever on bridged traffic. If you use a full-fledged Linux router. Most people don’t. Also, the performance impact makes bridge filtering impractical. You could also use `proxy_ndp` and routing to make this work with a single /64. However, again, this requires advanced setup.